# Prove that $f \ast g$ is continuous and bounded if $f\in L^1(R^n)$ and $g\in L^\propto (R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, convolution, lp-spaces

My Engliah is no so good and it is my first time to use this website, so I apologize for it if I didnot make myself clearly:)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644753/f-is-bounded-and-continious-rightarrow-the-convolution-integral-int-f-ta/644786#644786

Comment: And normally people show what they tried when they ask questions on this site.

Comment: @Lost1 I am very sorry for the inconvenience. It is all my fault.

Comment: oh do not apologise, it is fine. it is just next time, please show how you attempted to the question. My comment was just trying to make you aware the norm on this site. Asking a duplicate question unknowingly is fine. Everyone does that occasionally.

Comment: @Lost1 Well, thank you very much for telling me these things. I'll be more careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounded is straightforward: $$|f \ast g(x)| \le \int_{\mathbf R^n} |f(y)| |g(x-y)| \, dy \le ||g||_\infty \int_{\mathbf R^n} |f(y)| \, dy = ||f||_1 ||g||_\infty$$

As for continuity, observe that $$|f\ast g(x) - f\ast g(z)| = \left| \int_{\mathbf R^n} \left( f(y-x) - f(y-z) \right) g(y) \, dy \right| \le ||g||_\infty \int_{\mathbf R^n} |f(y-x) - f(y-z)| \, dy.$$

The fact that the right-hand side tends to zero as $|x-z| \to 0$ is a standard result in $L^1$ theory.