# Young inequality: Generalization on $\mathbb{T}$ space.

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, convolution, young-inequality

I'm interested in resolving this question that I find but on the $\mathbb{T}$ space.  ([Show that for any $f\in L^1$ and $g \in L^p(\mathbb R)$, $\lVert f ∗ g\rVert_p \leqslant \lVert f\rVert_1\lVert g\rVert_p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640674))

Now my question is, is it possible?

I mean I understand quite well the explanation that I found there but, if I take an $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and a $g\in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ is possible to prove, in the same way, that $f*g\in L^p$ for $1\le p\le \infty$ and that $||f*g||_{p}\le||f||_{1}||g||_{p}$? And if $p=\infty$? Is possible to prove that $||f*g||_{\infty}\le ||f||_{1}||g||_{\infty}$ if $f*g\in\mathbb{C(\mathbb{T})}$?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: The space $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the same proof works since it is a finite measure space .

*I am giving the same proof here again.*

We can define a finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{T}$ in the following way.
$$\mu(B)=\frac 1{\lVert g\rVert_1}\int_B|g(x)|\mathrm dx;$$for any measurable subset set $B$ of $\mathbb{T}$.

We have 
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|\cdot |g(y)|\mathrm dy\right)^p
=\left(\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|\mathrm d\mu(y)\right)^p\lVert g\rVert_1^p\leqslant\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|^p|\mathrm d\mu(y)\lVert g\rVert_1^p.$$

Now integrate over $x$ with respect to Lebesgue measure and use Fubini-Tonelli's theorem to conclude.
$$\lVert f ∗ g\rVert_p^p\leq\int_{\mathbb T}\left(\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|\cdot |g(y)|\mathrm dy\right)^p\mathrm dx
=\int_{\mathbb T}\lVert g\rVert_1^p\left(\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|\mathrm d\mu(y)\right)^p\mathrm dx$$$$\leq
\int_{\mathbb T}\lVert g\rVert_1^p\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|^p|\mathrm d\mu(y)|\mathrm dx=\lVert g\rVert_1^p\int_{\mathbb T}\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|^p\mathrm dx|\mathrm d\mu(y)|=\lVert g\rVert_1^p\int_{\mathbb T}\lVert f\rVert_p^p|\mathrm d\mu(y)|=\lVert g\rVert_1^p\lVert f\rVert_p^p\int_{\mathbb T}|\mathrm d\mu(y)|=\lVert g\rVert_1^p\lVert f\rVert_p^p\mu(\mathbb T).$$
And it is clear from the definition of $\mu$ that
$$ \mu(\mathbb T)=\frac 1{\lVert g\rVert_1}\int_{\mathbb T}|g(x)|\mathrm dx=1$$

for $p=\infty$
$$\lvert f ∗ g(x)\rvert\leq\int_{\mathbb T}|f(x-y)|\cdot |g(y)|\mathrm dy
\leq\int_{\mathbb T}\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\cdot |g(y)|\mathrm dy\leq\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\lVert g\rVert_1$$
$$
\implies \lVert f ∗ g\rVert_{\infty}\leq\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}\lVert g\rVert_1
$$

Comment: The linked question is about $L^p(\mathbb R)$, so why is $\mathbb T$ being a finite measure space relevant?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have edited my answer.

Comment: If there is any doubt please comment

Comment: It is $\mu$ which is finite.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I didn't understand

Comment: I would also like to mention here that it is a special case of a more general theorem. You can find the statement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality).

Comment: And what about the case with $p=\infty$?

Comment: @Mathematic_lover thank you. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Noob mathematician Thank you sir!